# How do I load a keras model for conversion to tf lite? Official API returns an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, h5py

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.2
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model( 'short-train.h5' ) # Your model's name
model = converter.convert()
file = open( 'model.tflite' , 'wb' ) 
file.write( model )
```

Is the code I am running. I receive the following error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-38aae5855f2c> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install tensorflow==2.2')
      2 import tensorflow as tf
----> 3 converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model( 'short-train.h5' ) # Your model's name
      4 model = converter.convert()
      5 file = open( 'model.tflite' , 'wb' )

AttributeError: type object 'TFLiteConverter' has no attribute 'from_keras_model'
```

This is the code given to me by https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter

This is the exact syntax given by tensorflow. What's the issue here?

---

Edit: I am now running this code as suggested:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# WHOLE MODEL
model = r'C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\face-mask-detector\mask_detector.model'

tflite_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_model)
tflite_save = converter.convert()
open("short-train.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_save)
```

However I received this error:

ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional #after trying to load the model

I can't find anything useful on this error. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

In short, change `from_keras_model` => `from_keras_model_file`

**For detail**:

If you use tensorflow v2 the converter `from_keras_model` is found in `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model`, but it is for loaded model instead of a path as you have shown.
However, for merging with tf1.x, u can activate older version with `tf.compat.v1` as you have done. But in tf1.x you have to include the model_path_file as `from_keras_model_file` instead of a loaded model

[image]

I see your problem as you have a Functional layer create by yourself, which is not Keras built-in model. You have to work around by this:

```
model = create_empty_model() #your model definition from keras that you create when you train
model.load_weights(".../model.h5",compile=False)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_model)
tflite_save = converter.convert()
open("short-train.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_save)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried using from_keras_model_file but I ended up with an error again. I'm sure I'm using tf==2.2.  The error:         ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional

Comment: The functional layer from Keras is the layer represent for Model, loss,...  which is not suitable if you train it on 2.2 and activate converter on 1.x as `compat.v1`. Therefore, try to load with `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model`. And as I have said, you have to input a model/not a path_string of directory to this method.

Comment: You have to model = load_model(path_to_model), then tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)

Comment: I just made an edit to the original question using this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the version of tensorflow the model is created in is equal to the version the tensorflow model is loaded into. Silly mistakes take a lot of time to correct but sometimes the cure is simple.

Answer (score -1):

You are using tensorflow v2 so you should try `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model` instead of `tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model` I don't have enough reputation to just comment sorry

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried your method and got this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'call'

Comment: As @dtlam26 said in his comment to his answer, the argument needs to be the path to the model and not the `.h5`